# How to put a size on a date_histogram aggregation

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm executing a query in elasticsearch. I need to have the number of hits for my attribute "end_date_ut" (type is Date and format is dateOptionalTime) for each month represented in the index.
For that, I'm using a date_histogram aggregation.

My query just bellow:

```
GET inc/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "appli": {
      "date_histogram": {
        "field": "end_date_ut",
        "interval": "month"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And here is a part of the result:

```
"hits": {
    "total": 517478,
    "max_score": 0,
    "hits": []
  },
  "aggregations": {
    "appli": {
      "buckets": [
        {
          "key_as_string": "2009-08-01T00:00:00.000Z",
          "key": 1249084800000,
          "doc_count": 0
        },
        {
          "key_as_string": "2009-09-01T00:00:00.000Z",
          "key": 1251763200000,
          "doc_count": 1
        },
        {
          "key_as_string": "2009-10-01T00:00:00.000Z",
          "key": 1254355200000,
          "doc_count": 2362
        },
        {
          "key_as_string": "2009-11-01T00:00:00.000Z",
          "key": 1257033600000,
          "doc_count": 5336
        },
        {
          "key_as_string": "2009-12-01T00:00:00.000Z",
          "key": 1259625600000,
          "doc_count": 7536
        },
        {
          "key_as_string": "2010-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
          "key": 1262304000000,
          "doc_count": 8864
        }
```

The problem is that I have too many buckets (results). When I'm using "terms aggregation", I don't have any problems because I can set a size, but with "date_histogram aggregation" I can't find a way to put a limit on my query result.

Comment: You need to add a `range` query in order to limit the time interval on which the `date_aggregation` is run.

Comment: It's a good solution but I don't want to limit the time interval. Is there another way to only get the 20 first results?

Comment: You could use `min_doc_count` to only include buckets that have data, i.e. the buckets with 0 documents would not come back in the response.

Comment: Indeed, It greatly reduces the number of results. I still have 74 buckets. So there is no way to forced a size on this type of aggregation?

Comment: Depends on your criteria... Which buckets do you need to filter out?

Comment: Well, I don't have any criteria.. I just want a certain number of results (the first ones) and I don't need the others. But now that I have a small number of results, I guess I could do it on my back end.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I suggest to use `min_doc_count` to only include buckets that have data, i.e. the buckets with 0 documents would not come back in the response.

```
GET inc/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "appli": {
      "date_histogram": {
        "field": "end_date_ut",
        "interval": "month",
        "min_doc_count": 1          <--- add this
      }
    }
  }
}
```

If you can, you can also add a `range` query in order to restrain the time interval on which the aggregation is run.

Answer (score 8):

```
{
    "size": 0,
    "aggs": {
        "by_minute": {
            "date_histogram": {
                "field": "createTime",
                "interval": "1m",
                "order": {
                    "_count": "desc"
                }
            },
            "aggs": {
                "top2": {
                    "bucket_sort": {
                        "sort": [],
                        "size": 2
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
{
    "took": 28,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 2,
        "successful": 2,
        "skipped": 0,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": 999999,
        "max_score": 0.0,
        "hits": []
    },
    "aggregations": {
        "by_minute": {
            "buckets": [
                {
                    "key_as_string": "2019-12-21T16:13:00.000Z",
                    "key": 1576944780000,
                    "doc_count": 6374
                },
                {
                    "key_as_string": "2019-12-21T16:10:00.000Z",
                    "key": 1576944600000,
                    "doc_count": 6327
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Adding that second "aggs" piece after the "date_histogram" is how to ask ES to only return top X date buckets by count. And it doesn't change the response format!